# man command, and output decoration (bold/underline/...)

Tags: terminal, command-line

When I do, say, a

```
man zsh
```

I get the zsh man page, parts of the text are in bold or underline, which makes it for easier reading. `man` is doing this for instance by inserting 0x08 control codes in its output, which then is interpreted by the Terminal for rendering underlined text.

When I do a

```
man zsh | cat
```

I of course don't see such decorations anymore, but just the plain text. This makes sense, because the program reading from the pipe, is usually not interested in seeing those control codes.

I assume that `man` checks whether the stdout is a tty or a pipe/file, an in the latter case it does not produce the output.

Now comes the puzzling part:

When I do a

```
man zsh | less
man zsh | xxd
man zsh | awk ....
```

I do still see the decorations (underline etc.) at the receiving end of the pipe. How is this possilble? `man` does not know whether the process it pipes the output to, wants to see the control code, and `cat` and `head` certainly don't have the ability to filter out such decorations.

Comment: Man pages are formatted using the [roff typesetting standard](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/roff.7.html). `cat` and `head` are not roff formatters.

Comment: @allan neither is `less` :-)

Comment: So `more` or `less`, this doesn’t format correctly @nohillside?  ;-). (Sorry, I couldn’t resist)

Comment: @allan Right. It get's even more interesting, did you try `man zsh | cat | less`?

Comment: Which basically leads to the answer that it's not `man` knowing what is at the other end of the pipe but rather `cat` suppressing control information on output.

Comment: @nohillside, just doing a bit of research on bsd version of man…. `man` uses a pager to display the output - usually `more` or `less`.  `man` knows nothing about where it’s output is going.  Have a look at `/private/etc/man.conf` for all of the PAGER settings

Comment: @allan I know. The question is not actually about `man` though, more about `cat`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The theory

The `man` program itself, doesn't talk directly to the terminal. It produces output which is text with a small amount of formatting. Another program, a *[pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager)*, generally [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)), handles the user interaction (scrolling, searching, etc.) and applies some basic formatting.

In addition to basic pagination (breaking lines, indenting, etc.), man can use three ways to make text stand out: capital letters, bold and underline. Capital letters are just different characters from lowercase letters. For bold and underline, man uses the [backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#%5EH) (BS) [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_code):

- The three-character sequence *c* BS *c* indicates that the character *c* should   be displayed in bold.
- The three-character sequence `_` BS *c* (where [`_`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore) is the underscore character) indicates that the character *c* should be displayed underlined.

(There is no provision for bold underscore, and I don't know offhand which way `_` BS `_` would be interpreted.)

These sequences are inspired from what you could do with a [typewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter), and in particular with a [teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) which was a common interface to computers when the `man` program was originally written: if you print a character, then use the BS control to move back left and print that character again, you get a bolder character. If you use BS to overstrike a `_` with another character, that other character is underlined.

[Character-oriented video terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Character-oriented_terminal) don't overstrike characters in this way, and modern terminal emulator programs present a similar interface. Terminals interpret the BS character as an instruction to move left by one position. When displaying a character at a position, the terminal completely overwrites whatever was previously there.

So it's the job of the pager to interpret convert *c* BS *c* and `_` BS *c* to instructions for the terminal to display *c* in bold or underline. The way to do this depends on the [terminal capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_capabilities), although in practice all modern terminals use the same escape sequences for basic functionality like bold and underline.

#### The practice

When you run `man zsh`, the `man` command invokes `less`. `less` converts BS-based bold/underline into formatting escape sequences that the terminal understands. So you see the text formatted as intended.

When you run `man zsh | cat`, the `man` program [detects that its output is not a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22162/ls-command-operating-differently-depending-on-recipient/22164#22164), so it doesn't run `less`: it just prints the output that it would have passed to `less`. `cat` just passes its input through unchanged. The terminal sees sequences like *c* BS *c* and `_` BS *c*, and in either case, BS erases the previous character so the visual effect is just like a plain *c*.

When you run `man zsh | less` or `man zsh | cat | less`, the `less` command receives the same input that it would receive if `man` had invoked `less` directly. However, the behavior may be different because `man` can invoke `less` with some non-default command options. (From a quick check, this doesn't appear to happen on macOS.)

You can disable less's handling of backspace by passing the `-u` [command line option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html#OPTIONS). Run either `LESS=-u man man` or `man man | less -u` to see what happens if `less` just passes the BS character unchanged to the terminal: the visual effect is the same as when not running less (but less still does pagination). Run `LESS=-U man man` or `man man | less -U` to see a visual rendering of the BS character as`^H` in reverse video.

Other ways to see the BS characters include:

- `man man | cat -v` which translates each BS character into the two-character sequence `^H`.
- `man man | hd` which shows a hex dump of the text. You'll see sequences like `4e 08 4e 41 08 41 4d 08 4d 45 08` — `08`=backspace, `4e`=N, `41`=A, `4d`=M, `45`=E so this is NAME in bold.
- `man man >out.txt` and open `out.txt` in an editor. How the editor shows control characters depends on the editor and possibly on its configuration.

If you want to print your own, you can pass `\b` or `\010` in the first argument of the [`printf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) terminal command to print a backspace character. Try these:

```
printf 'Normal\nB\bBo\bol\bld\bd\n_\bU_\bn_\bd_\be_\br_\bl_\bi_\bn_\be\n'
printf 'Normal\nB\bBo\bol\bld\bd\n_\bU_\bn_\bd_\be_\br_\bl_\bi_\bn_\be\n' | cat
printf 'Normal\nB\bBo\bol\bld\bd\n_\bU_\bn_\bd_\be_\br_\bl_\bi_\bn_\be\n' | cat -v
printf 'Normal\nB\bBo\bol\bld\bd\n_\bU_\bn_\bd_\be_\br_\bl_\bi_\bn_\be\n' | hd
printf 'Normal\nB\bBo\bol\bld\bd\n_\bU_\bn_\bd_\be_\br_\bl_\bi_\bn_\be\n' | less
printf 'Normal\nB\bBo\bol\bld\bd\n_\bU_\bn_\bd_\be_\br_\bl_\bi_\bn_\be\n' | less -u
printf 'Normal\nB\bBo\bol\bld\bd\n_\bU_\bn_\bd_\be_\br_\bl_\bi_\bn_\be\n' | less -U
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `cat` strips control characters when the output goes to a terminal. From `man cat`:

```
-e  Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display a dollar
    sign (‘$’) at the end of each line.

-t  Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display tab
    characters as ‘^I’.

-v  Display non-printing characters so they are visible.  Control characters
    print as ‘^X’ for control-X; the delete character (octal 0177) prints
    as ‘^?’.  Non-ASCII characters (with the high bit set) are printed as ‘M-’
    (for meta) followed by the character for the low 7 bits.
```

So, running

- `man man | cat` will strip control characters,
- `man man | cat -e` will show them (as will `cat -v` and `cat -t`),
- `man man | cat | less` will pass control characters to `less` (making the `cat` part basically a no-op).

Comment: If the `PAGER` variable in `/private/etc/man.conf` is set to `less` (mine is on Catalina)  then piping to less again will have no effect, just as the OP saw  when he did `man zsh | less`

Comment: @allan `less` is the default pager for `man` :-) But `man` is a distraction here, the same would happen if you run `troff -options input.troff | ...`.

Comment: I was just putting that there to address the quasi-question in the OP.  It was assumed that `man` checks where the output is going when in reality it is the pager doing the heavy lifting.

Comment: No, `cat` does not strip control characters. It leaves them unchanged. The options you cite _replace_ control characters by sequences of visible characters, and will not produce bold or underline text.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' `man man | cat` doesn't show any control characters

Comment: Sure, it doesn't _show_ them: the terminal treats the backspace character as an instruction to move one position to the left, overwriting the previous character, so *c1* BS *c2* has the same visual effect as just *c2* and you can't tell that `man` wrote *c1* BS *c2*. But `man` did indeed write *c* BS *c* for a bold character *c* and `_` BS *c* for an underlined *c*.

Comment: All you have to do is enter the command `man echo | cat | hexdump -Cv` to see @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' is correct.